# Using a ternary operator in a sqlalchemy filter statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a one to many relationship defined in sqlalchemy.

My parent table has a bunch of children. And those children have start and end times attached to them. The times are datetime.time objects in which the hours must be between 0 and 23. When the end time occurs before the start time (like starting at 8:00 and ending at 01:00), a simple query like `(Children.start_time <= search_time) & (search_time >= Children.end_time)` doesn't work.

Is there a way to make this statement work?

```
        parent_query = Parents.join(Parents.children).filter(
                (Child.start_time <= search_time) &\
                (
                    (
                        extract('hour', Child.end_time) if\ 
                        extract('hour', Child.end_time) < extract('hour', Hours.start_time) else\
                        extract('hour', Child.end_time) + 24
                    )
                    >= search_hour
                ) &\
                (Child.end_time.minute >= search_minute)
                )
```

I'm getting a `TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a [`CASE`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) statement:

```
case([
    (extract('hour', Child.end_time) < extract('hour', Hours.start_time), extract('hour', Child.end_time))
], else_=extract('hour', Child.end_time) + 24)
```

Comment: Good answer, but you might also want to explain why the ternary operator doesn't work.  The reason is that when using `if`/`else`, Python tries to evaluate the branch condition while the query is being defined, which doesn't make sense.  Using `case()` adds the conditional to the SQL of the query.